# create new col based on other columns - faster method

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this.

```
DATA <- data.frame(
    CARS = c("PA", "PI", "PA", "PI", "PA", "PA", "PI", "PI"),
    EYE_SIGHT= c("GOOD", "GOOD", "POOR", "POOR", "GOOD", "POOR", "GOOD", "GOOD"))
```

I want to create NEW_COL in R based on these conditions. If EYE_SIGHT  = Good and CARS = PA, write 0. If EYE_SIGHT = GOOD and CARS = PI, write 1. if EYE_SIGHT  = POOR and CARS = PA, write 3. If EYE_SIGHT = POOR and CARS = PI, write 4.

This code does the job.

```
Data1 <- DATA %>%
    mutate(NEW_COL = case_when(EYE_SIGHT == "GOOD"  & CARS == "PA" ~ 0, EYE_SIGHT == "GOOD"  & CARS == "PI" ~ 1, EYE_SIGHT == "POOR"  & CARS == "PA" ~ 3, EYE_SIGHT == "POOR"  & CARS == "PI" ~ 4))
```

and gives the correct output.

```
CARS EYE_SIGHT NEW_COL
1   PA      GOOD       0
2   PI      GOOD       1
3   PA      POOR       3
4   PI      POOR       4
5   PA      GOOD       0
6   PA      POOR       3
7   PI      GOOD       1
8   PI      GOOD       1
```

But, I believe there must be a faster way of working this out to save time – especially when working with a large data. Any advice guys. Thanks

Comment: This is a bit of an open-ended question, but typically you'd make tables with matching ids and join them together when you're dealing with many categories. See the examples in `?left_join` for instance.

Comment: I don't think the question is about joining tables together.

Comment: I do. What about `LKUP <- data.frame(EYE_SIGHT = c("GOOD","GOOD","POOR","POOR"), CARS = c("PA","PI","PA","PI"), NEW_COL = c(0,1,3,4))` and then `DATA %>% left_join(LKUP, by=c("EYE_SIGHT","CARS"))` ? Seems to work as intended and will allow you to deal with many categories and changing values by just updating the `LKUP` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be faster to put together if you have alot of variables to write in a `case_when` statement.

```r
library(prodlim)
DATA <- data.frame(
  CARS = c("PA", "PI", "PA", "PI", "PA", "PA", "PI", "PI"),
  EYE_SIGHT= c("GOOD", "GOOD", "POOR", "POOR", "GOOD", "POOR", "GOOD", "GOOD"))


# All possible combinations
combinations<-unique(DATA[,c("CARS","EYE_SIGHT")])
# Find Matching rows
index<-row.match(DATA,combinations)
# Revalue
index[index==1]<-0
index[index==2]<-1

DATA$NEW_COL<- index


DATA

  CARS EYE_SIGHT NEW_COL
1   PA      GOOD       0
2   PI      GOOD       1
3   PA      POOR       3
4   PI      POOR       4
5   PA      GOOD       0
6   PA      POOR       3
7   PI      GOOD       1
8   PI      GOOD       1
```